# i2c address conflict between MPU6050 and DS3231

Tags: i2c

I am using MPU6050 onboard a GY-86 module. I also have a DS3231 RTC module. when i searched each data sheet i found that DS3231 and MPU6050 have same i2c address which is 0x68. I have read in the MPU data sheet that if i connect the AD0 pin to 3.3 the the address becomes 0x69. but i can't find any AD0 on my module . i only have vcc-3.3v-SCL-SDA-INTa-FSYNC-DROY
I think i have to change i2c address of mpu6050 or ds3231. so that they won't conflict . how can i change i2c dress of MPU or DS module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [GY-86 schematic](http://www.thaieasyelec.com/downloads/ESEN246/GY-86_SCH.jpg) I found, the AD0 pin is hard grounded on the board. This means that unless you can find a trace on the board to cut (unlikely), there is no way to change the MPU6050 slave address. As far as I can see, the DS2321 cannot change its address either.

This leaves you with a few choices:

1. Change out on of the devices to a different model with a different address. I expect you really don't want to do this.
2. If your master device (which you did not specify) has multiple I2C bus controllers, hook each device to a different bus.
3. Use an I2C multiplexer to put the devices on different "virtual" busses. Here's a [module](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-tca9548a-1-to-8-i2c-multiplexer-breakout/overview) with a 1-8 multiplexer which should do the job (though only a 1-2 is really necessary).

Comment: Oh Bad luck:(
I am using arduino mega which has only once I2C bus. i will decide between your 1 and 3 option :) Thanks for your help.